# Form not generated by template

Tags: python, django

I've started working on Django forms since not long ago. I've been letting forms generate by them self simply by writing :

```
{{ test_form.as_p  }}
```

which worked successfuly.

I've then decided to work around to customize this template but for some reason the line :

```
{{ form.subject }}
```

doesn't show a form. Did i have misunderstood the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) ? I've also checked the HTML generated and it has kind of simply jumped over the {{ form.suject }}

Here is the code :

The template :

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.subject.errors }}
    <label for="id_subject">Email subject:</label>
    {{ form.subject }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.message.errors }}
    <label for="id_message">Your message:</label>
    {{ form.message }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.sender.errors }}
    <label for="id_sender">Your email address:</label>
    {{ form.sender }}
</div>
<p><input type="submit" value="Send message" /></p>
```

And the view associated :

```
def contact(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = contact_form(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']
        sender = form.cleaned_data['sender']
        recipents = ['grit.erlum@gmail.com']
        send_mail(subject, message, sender, recipents)
        print 'mail sent'
return render_to_response('contact.html', {'contact_form' : contact_form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And of course the Form Class :

```
class contact_form(forms.Form):

subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
message = forms.CharField(max_length=1000, widget=forms.Textarea)
sender = forms.EmailField()
```

Comment: It looks like in your view you're rendering the form as `contact_form` in your context, and you're not passing the `form` instance to it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view does not have `contact_form` variable defined, but you are passing that to `render_to_response`.
You also need to create an unbound version of your form and pass it to `render_to_response` like:

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = contact_form(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ...
    else:
        form = contact_form() # An unbound form
        return render_to_response('contact.html', {'form' : form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your render_to_response, just change:

{'contact_form' : contact_form}

to

{'form' : contact_form}

or your template, change {{ form.xxx }} into {{ contact_form.xxx }}

Comment: Could you explain me the difference ? And why does it work like that ? (it now works correctly)